# How can I return an error in Shiny if my action button causes app to crash

Tags: r, database, shiny

I have an action button that writes a dataframe to a database, but if there is an error in writing the dataframe to the database, the app crashes. An error is returned in the R console, but not in the app UI. How can I return the error to the app so the user can make the necessary changes, then write the data to the database successfully.

Here is a version of my action button observe event:

```
observeEvent(input$actionbutton, {

    DBI::dbWriteTable(con, SQL('database.table'), data$df, append=T, row.names=F)

    showModal( modalDialog( title=paste0("RPostgreSQL table Updated"),
                            br(),
                            div(tags$b(paste0("Your new data has been written to the Postgres database"), style = "color: green;"))
    ))
  })
```

Comment: Maybe the answer you are looking for is in this post (?): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038676/r-trycatch-in-place-with-err-and-warn-handlers-but-shiny-still-crashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dupe link is appropriate, here it is customized for your code.

```r
observeEvent(input$actionbutton, {
    ret <- tryCatch(
      DBI::dbWriteTable(con, SQL('database.table'), data$df, append=T, row.names=F),
      error = function(e) conditionMessage(e))
    if (isTRUE(ret)) {
      showModal( modalDialog( title=paste0("RPostgreSQL table Updated"),
                              br(),
                              div(tags$b(paste0("Your new data has been written to the Postgres database"), style = "color: green;"))
      ))
    } else {
      # 'ret' is a string that contains the error message,
      # you can use that in a modalDialog
    }
  })
```